# Impact of having an international domain?

Tags: domains

I'm looking to get an .es domain. Just wondering how this might impact search results and rankings as I'd like to make the website available worldwide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes much of a difference. Search engine rankings are now weighted more to actual page content and social presence, instead of the actual domain name.

Answer (score 6):

It does make a difference. All TLDs are treated equally in a google.com web search.

However, TLDs do affect your search results for country specific searches. For example, a .me or .tv domain will not rank as well as a .us website in a google.us web search. Also, a .co.uk site will rank better then a .us site in a google.co.uk search. This is because country specific searches give precedence to local websites.

So if you are targeting a specific country or region, try to use the TLD for that country or region. If not then the TLD does not make a difference.